# Snowpark UDF locking mechanism

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pickle, user-defined-functions

In Snowpark version 0.7.0 there was a new locking mechanism added to the UDFs - from Snowflake's release notes:
`Added a lock to a UDF or UDTF when it is called for the first time per thread.`

When I create a new UDF, the following code is automatically added to the UDF:

```
import pickle

func = pickle.loads(bytes.fromhex('<python_function_hex_code_here>'))

from threading import RLock

lock = RLock()

class InvokedFlag:
    def __init__(self):
        self.invoked = False

def lock_function_once(f, flag):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not flag.invoked:
            with lock:
                if not flag.invoked:
                    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
                    flag.invoked = True
                    return result
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


invoked = InvokedFlag()

def compute(arg1):
    return lock_function_once(func, invoked)(arg1)
```

I'm guessing that the part of the code that loads the function from hex-string is performed only once, in the first thread that acquires the lock, but it's not clear from the code how it's done.

What is the order of the logics, performed by Snowpark's threads?
How are the variables/objects shared between threads that run in different workers at different instances?

Thank you!